# Configure a new kubernetes node automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling, gpu

I configured a Kubernetes cluster with GPU in AWS, and one of the steps is configuring the nodes to enable Nvidia runtime by default.

So when I configured cluster auto scaler, the cluster scales up successfully but the new node still needs to be configured to use Nvidia as a default runtime.

My goal is to configure this step automatically, I wonder if there is a way to do this with Kubernetes, like specifying the commands to execute in startup in the instance group. (just like in GCP where you are able to define a startup script or in AWS called a user data for launching scripts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting resource [here](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/instance_groups/#additionaluserdata) that helped me to achieve my goal above.

so the it's possible to define additional user data section in the instance group configuration.

In my case I was about to enable Nvidia runtime which I achieved as follows:

```
spec:
  additionalUserData:
  - content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      sudo sed -i '2i "default-runtime": "nvidia",' /etc/docker/daemon.json && sudo systemctl restart docker
    name: script.sh
    type: text/x-shellscript
```